# Makefile several sources in subdirectories

Tags: makefile

I have several .yml files in directory that are input of a python script to create .json files, .json are in subdirectories with same name than source without extension.

Makefile works with one target but not with several, it creates circular dependencies

```
sources = DOC-A1 DOC-A2
pyscript=~/Documents/Programmation/myscript.py

all: $(sources)/$(sources)-ref.json $(sources)/$(sources)-enr.json

$(sources)/$(sources)-ref.json: $(sources).yml
    python3 $(pyscript) --ref --graph $<

$(sources)/$(sources)-enr.json: $(sources).yml
    python3 $(pyscript) --enr --graph $<
```

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental confusion about how make expands variables.  See this answer for help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60591103/939557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the sources files: DOC-A1.yml DOC-A2.yml then you need to do something like:

```
# Source file base list (without yml extensions)
sources = DOC-A1 DOC-A2
# Create a list of ref output files from the base names
outputs_ref = $(addsuffix -ref.json,$(sources))
# Do the same with the enr files
outputs_enr = $(addsuffix -enr.json,$(sources))

# Print the list of output files you want (for ref)
$(info outputs_ref: $(outputs_ref))
$(info outputs_enr: $(outputs_enr))

pyscript=~/Documents/Programmation/myscript.py

# All now depends on the two lists of output files
all: $(outputs_ref) $(outputs_enr)

# Pattern-rule to generate -ref.json files, dependant on a .yml file with the same base-name
%-ref.json : %.yml
    @echo python3 $(pyscript) --ref --graph $<

# Pattern-rule to generate -enr.json files, dependant on a .yml file with the same base-name
%-enr.json: %.yml
    @echo python3 $(pyscript) --enr --graph $<
```

**Note:** The rules I have used only print out the commands - to run, remove the `@echo` part from the start of the lines

**Update** I forgot to mention about the pattern rule. A rule like: `%.a : %.b` will be expanded for all targets that match `%.a` where `%` is a wildcard. There must be a matching `%.b` dependency where again, `%` is a wildcard. So if you have the source files `1.b, 2.b, 3.b` and you want to compile them into `1.a, 2.a, 3.a` then the pattern rule `%.a : %.b` will do this for you.

To answer your question about circular dependency: Here is your original rule:

```
$(sources)/$(sources)-ref.json: $(sources).yml
    python3 $(pyscript) --ref --graph $<
```

This is not a pattern rule so it expands the variables as-is so you end up with:

```
DOC-A1 DOC-A2/DOC-A1 DOC-A2-ref.json: DOC-A1 DOC-A2.yml
    python3 $(pyscript) --ref --graph $<
```

Here we have just replaced `$(sources)` with `DOC-A1 DOC-A2`. You can see that `DOC-A1` is both a target *and* a dependency (i.e. circular). There is also a load of other "junk" that I am sure you did not intend :)

Comment: The .json files being in subdirectories, this doesn't work as needed. With your help I managed to improve writing:
 outputs_ref = $(foreach source, $(sources), $(addsuffix -ref.json,$(source)/$(source)))
but now it doesn't know how to build the .json having  a target 
DOC-A1/DOC-A1-ref.json

Comment: @Penbeuz ah, yes there is an issue here now if you want the subdir to be different for every object, because you can't easily make the pattern rule work. You are trying to have the rules like: `DOC-A1/DOC-A1-ref.json : DOC-A1.yml` but you can't write `%/%-ref.json : %.yml`. You could do: `DOC-A1//%-ref.json : %.yml`, but then you need to repeat the rule for each one  (i.e. you need a `DOC-A2/%-ref.json : %.yml` rule which will be identical to the first one). Some re-structuring will be requirerd to tidy this up...

Comment: thank, will do like that, I don't have that many different subdirectories